# PyQt5, Qlabel text in multiple colors

Tags: python, pyqt5

how can i set multiple colors inside a Qlabel text?
for example:

```
Qlabel.setText("Hello World!")
```

I want the "Hello" to be in blue, the "World" in red & the "!" in green
is it possible?

I found that answer online for QT but this is not Python language:

```
ql->setText("<font color=\"blue\">Hello</font> <font color=\"red\">World</font><font color=\"green">!</font>");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easy, if you're familiar with HTML:
Do something like this:

```
QLabel.setText('<font color="blue">Hello</font><font color="red"> World</font><font color="green">!</font>')
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thats amazing... I didnt know we can use HTML in python. thank you!

Comment: No problem! Would you mind marking this as the right answer? This will help others who have the same query too. :)